# Data layer abstraction for Windows Phone and Windows 8 Modern apps?

Tags: database, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, abstraction

I'm trying to port my WP apps to Windows 8 while maintaining portable model and viewmodel classes. However, my apps have used SQLCE for Windows Phone 7, and so my original model classes are all decorated up with attributes for mapping to SQLCE tables. Since SQLCE isn't available for WinRT apps, I want to abstract data access so that I can continue using SQLCE on the phone, but use SQLite on Windows 8.

Has anyone come up with a sane, working abstraction layer that doesn't eliminate the ability to use `IQueryable`? Similarly, anyone have success using XML mapping for SQLCE on Windows Phone as opposed to attribute mapping? It'd be nice if I didn't have to manually convert between my model classes and DAL analogues.

(I have a [bit of a rant](http://chris.charabaruk.com/2013/04/sharing-models-between-windows-phone-and-windows-8-an-exercise-in-futility/) about this on my blog, which may help provide further background on my problem.)

Comment: I'm in the same boat. All my data access was in a seperate class library with nothing else in it, so I have just rewritten this component for WinRT exposing the same members and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I can still reuse all my ViewModels and Views, just the entity classes have a different implementation (but the same public interface).

It's not ideal, but it seemed to be the only way to do things (until I can use Esent in WP)
Regarding the IQueryable requirement: I'm not using this so it isn't a problem for me, and unfortunately I have no real solution for this.

Comment: The issue there is when you have your viewmodels, etc. in a portable class library, which is the setup I have going now. Since PCL assemblies can't reference platform-specific ones, I still need to have a bunch of interfaces that my data access assemblies implement, not to mention interfaces or true POCOs for model objects. I might simply have to convert between DAL model classes and model classes within my portable assembly.

Comment: Losing `IQueryable` support will really, really suck, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've determined that having a per-platform "core" assembly for portable code (viewmodels, helpers, etc.) and a separate assembly per database/backing store (SqlCe, Sqlite, etc.) that the platform-specific core assemblies reference seems to work. This means that my model classes are still defined in the DAL assemblies, but I at least can provide a simple, common interface (defined in each DAL assembly, unfortunately, because of the DAL model classes) that still provides me with IQueryable support.

Thanks to "copy as link" in Visual Studio, setting up the core assemblies and ensuring that the common database service interface is the same for each DAL assembly is pretty easy. With `#ifdef` I can even reuse a lot of the DAL model class files and conditionally compile attributes, database-specific code, etc. which allows me to use "copy as link" for them too.

```
public interface IDataService
{
    IQueryable<ModelType1> ModelType1 { get; }
    IQueryable<ModelType2> ModelType2 { get; }

    void AddModelType1(ModelType1 item);
    void RemoveModelType1(ModelType1 item);

    void AddModelType2(ModelType2 item);
    void RemoveModelType2(ModelType2 item);

    void CreateDatabase();
    void ResetDatabase();
}
```

The resulting map of references is kind of like this:

```
System.Data.Linq -> App.Data.SqlCe -> App.Core.WP -> App.WP
                        /                /
             (some shared code)  (all shared code)
                      /                /
Sqlite -> App.Data.Sqlite -> App.Core.Win8 -> App.Win8
```

It's nowhere near as clean as I'd like, but at least it seems to work.

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I have done. You're right, it should be cleaner. I really wish they would just give us the entity framework on WP and RT.